# Fallout 76 Mutation probability calculator

Tags: probability

So my question is a bit of a wordy one, ill attempt to keep it concise;

In Fallout 76 you can gain mutations. There are 19 of them in total and each come with both a good and negative effect, making each mutation good or bad depending on the individuals play-style.

When you gain a mutation, it is random which one you get, and when you cure a mutation it is random which mutation you cure.

There is one exception to this rule; The mutations Carnivore and Herbivore are mutually exclusive - you can only have one of them, meaning the total number of mutations the player can have is 18 out of the total 19.

This makes figuring out the best method of gaining your desired mutations difficult.

I am currently working on a 'calculator' that will allow you to select which mutations are good, bad, or neutral, as well as which mutations you currently have.

So, basically my question is this; Assuming the chance to gain or cure each mutation is equal, what is the best way of finding the optimal method to gain your desired mutation make-up?

Since this will be an application, a large number of calculations can be done relatively simply; So my original idea was to simply brute-force the math and check every possible outcome for X # of steps into the future and decide the best; But im certain there has to be a better way

Comment: What are the methods under consideration? In the game, what move(s) do I make to either gain or cure a mutation?

Comment: Mutations are gained by becoming irradiated in the game and can be cured with an item; Its fairly easy and reliable to do.

Currently my assumptions are that the proper answer would lie between the two extremes, those being;
A) Gain mutations constantly until you have acquired all the mutations you want, then proceed to cure away all the ones you dont want; Repeat until complete

B) Gain mutations until you acquire one you dont want; switch to curing until its gone; repeat until complete

Comment: By "optimal" do you mean the method that will result in the smallest total number of mutations and cures until success?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Im honestly not even sure where to begin

Comment: I have another question.  When you get a random mutation, is it always different from the mutations you already have, or is there a chance of getting a duplicate?